# 'NoneType' object is not iterable error when using read_sql for teradata

Tags: python, pandas, teradata, pyodbc

I use pyodbc to connect to Teradata, and use read_sql to select data.  This used to work when I used Python2.7 and pyodbc3.0.7.  Now that I switched to Python3.5 and pyodbc4.0.17, I get error "'NoneType' object is not iterable".
My pandas version is 0.23.1

I did some search here and tried to add "set nocount on", but Teradata doesn't seem to have this equivalent.

Here's how I connect to teradata:

```py
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=***;PWD=***',autocommit=True)
```

And here's how I try to get data:

```py
DF=pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * from tbl",con=cnxn)
```

The table is not empty, and I should get thousands of records.  Instead, this is the error I get:

```py
  File "/Applications/anaconda2/envs/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 314, in read_sql_query
    parse_dates=parse_dates, chunksize=chunksize)
  File "/Applications/anaconda2/envs/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1414, in read_query
    columns = [col_desc[0] for col_desc in cursor.description]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Any pointers on how I can fix this?

Comment: The error means that either `cursor.description` is `None` or one of the elements of `cursor.description` is `None`.

Comment: Would you please elaborate?  What is cursor.description?  What role does it play here?

Comment: `cursor.description` contains descriptions of all the columns returned by the SQL query. The [documentation](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pyodbc/wikis/Cursor.wiki) says: **This attribute will be None for operations that do not return rows or if one of the execute methods has not been called** I'm not sure why it's `None` in your case, since it's a `SELECT` query and pandas should be calling `execute()`.